# Nautilus doesn't open initially but after a long time it starts working fine

Tags: nautilus

I recently moved from 16.04 to 18.04. When I login to the system no files are shown on the desktop and 'file' icon also doesn't open. When I ran the command `time nautilus` it gave the following response:

```
Failed to register: Timeout was reached

real    0m25.074s
user    0m0.042s
sys 0m0.025s
```

But after 5 minutes all the windows suddenly open and folder in the desktop also start showing up. The response of the same command is as follows:

```
real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.038s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Although, I can access all the files and folder using terminal. Also, it works fine even after I issue the command `nautilus -q` and doesn't take much time. It seems like the problem is only when I login to the system. Although this was not the case with ubuntu 16.04 where everything started instantaneously.

Edit: I removed and installed nautilus again but no help.

Output of `free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        2.7G        1.4G        268M        3.5G        4.3G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Output of `sysctl vm.swappiness`

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
ls: cannot access '/home/bhavy/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

Output of `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun  7 01:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun  7 01:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  7 01:52 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  7 01:52 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Output of `cat /var/log/syslog|grep nautilus`

```
Jun  7 18:22:41 bhavy-HP whoopsie[1956]: [18:22:41] Parsing /var/crash/_usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash.
Jun  7 18:22:41 bhavy-HP whoopsie[1956]: [18:22:41] Uploading /var/crash/_usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash.
Jun  7 18:30:30 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:30 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: message repeated 2 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Jun  7 18:30:30 bhavy-HP nautilus[4565]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:30 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: message repeated 44 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP dbus-daemon[1403]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.269' (uid=1000 pid=4565 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP nautilus[4565]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP nautilus[4565]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP nautilus[4565]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:31 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: message repeated 191 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Jun  7 18:30:32 bhavy-HP nautilus[4565]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:33 bhavy-HP nautilus[4565]: message repeated 129 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
Jun  7 18:30:37 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
Jun  7 18:30:38 bhavy-HP nautilus-deskto[4472]: message repeated 143 times: [ can't init metadata tree /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied]
```

There was one system program error detected window as well. When I looked at the `/var/crash` folder with `ls`. It gave the following output

```
_usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash  _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.upload  _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.uploaded
```

Edit 2:
The following two commands `sudo grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` prints nothing.

For `ls -al /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/` the output is

```
drwx------  2 bhavy bhavy  4096 Apr  1 13:47  .
drwx------ 37 bhavy bhavy  4096 Jun  7 19:32  ..
-rw-------  1 root  root  90096 Apr 14  2018  home
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  32768 Apr 14  2018  home-520671b4.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  1068 May 10  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 May 10  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D-ea794164.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   892 Apr  1 13:47 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Apr  1 13:50 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D-96429231.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  1904 Mar 17 14:49 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C008%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Mar 17 14:49 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C008%5D-1ef4e927.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   988 Jan  3  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C019%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jan  3  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C019%5D-295b34d0.log'
-rw-------  1 root  root  23428 Apr 20  2018  root
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  32768 Apr 20  2018  root-a7cd5a51.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   528 Oct 16  2019 'sftp:host=172.27.28.229,user=jatindev'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Oct 16  2019 'sftp:host=172.27.28.229,user=jatindev-50511b70.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   360 Jun 28  2018  uuid-13F2-1B57
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jun 28  2018  uuid-13F2-1B57-ef6bea9f.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   152 Dec 15  2017  uuid-15F6-1853
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Dec 15  2017  uuid-15F6-1853-dd280f53.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   168 Feb  5  2019  uuid-1CB5-2250
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Feb  5  2019  uuid-1CB5-2250-57328334.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  3652 Oct 14  2019  uuid-2E18-2B51
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Oct 14  2019  uuid-2E18-2B51-148fcb14.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  7444 Jan  1  2019  uuid-70F1-3FAB
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jan  1  2019  uuid-70F1-3FAB-80580a55.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  3036 Mar  4  2018  uuid-858A-D414
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Mar  4  2018  uuid-858A-D414-6d31293d.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   716 Aug  6  2018  uuid-CC63-C4D1
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Aug  6  2018  uuid-CC63-C4D1-86f630c5.log
```

Edit 3: After allocating swap memory and changing ownership of gvfs-metadata
Output of `free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        2.1G        3.0G        221M        2.5G        5.1G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G
```

Output of `ls -al /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`

```
total 716
drwx------  2 bhavy bhavy  4096 Jun  7 20:12  .
drwx------ 37 bhavy bhavy  4096 Jun  7 20:12  ..
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy 90096 Apr 14  2018  home
-rw-r--r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jun  7 20:12  home-520671b4.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy 95220 Jun  7 20:12  home.AQPML0
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  1068 May 10  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 May 10  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D-ea794164.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   892 Apr  1 13:47 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Apr  1 13:50 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D-96429231.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  1904 Mar 17 14:49 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C008%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Mar 17 14:49 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C008%5D-1ef4e927.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   988 Jan  3  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C019%5D'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jan  3  2018 'mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C019%5D-295b34d0.log'
-rw-------  1 root  root  23428 Apr 20  2018  root
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  32768 Apr 20  2018  root-a7cd5a51.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   528 Oct 16  2019 'sftp:host=172.27.28.229,user=jatindev'
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Oct 16  2019 'sftp:host=172.27.28.229,user=jatindev-50511b70.log'
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   360 Jun 28  2018  uuid-13F2-1B57
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jun 28  2018  uuid-13F2-1B57-ef6bea9f.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   152 Dec 15  2017  uuid-15F6-1853
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Dec 15  2017  uuid-15F6-1853-dd280f53.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   168 Feb  5  2019  uuid-1CB5-2250
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Feb  5  2019  uuid-1CB5-2250-57328334.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  3652 Oct 14  2019  uuid-2E18-2B51
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Oct 14  2019  uuid-2E18-2B51-148fcb14.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  7444 Jan  1  2019  uuid-70F1-3FAB
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Jan  1  2019  uuid-70F1-3FAB-80580a55.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy  3036 Mar  4  2018  uuid-858A-D414
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Mar  4  2018  uuid-858A-D414-6d31293d.log
-rw-------  1 bhavy bhavy   716 Aug  6  2018  uuid-CC63-C4D1
-rw-rw-r--  1 bhavy bhavy 32768 Aug  6  2018  uuid-CC63-C4D1-86f630c5.log
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: You have to tell me that you've updated your question by sending me a comment that starts with @heynnema, or I'll surely miss the update. You have two problems. Edit your question and show me `sudo grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` and `ls -al /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`.

Comment: @heynnema I am sorry for that. Please find the updated question.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### swap

You have no swap, as seen in `free -h`.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        2.7G        1.4G        268M        3.5G        4.3G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

We'll create a 4 GB `/swapfile`.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. I suggest to copy/paste.

```sh
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Then reboot and verify proper swap operation.

#### gvfs-metadata

You've been starting `nautilus` with `sudo`. You should be using `sudo -H` when starting GUI apps as root from the terminal.

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home*

sudo chmod 664 /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home*.log

sudo rm -i /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root*
```

#### desktop-icons

Reinstall missing gnome-shell extension:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to enable/configure *Desktop Icons*.

#### ~/.cache

We found corruption in the `~/.cache` folder. Recreated a new folder and `Files` now works.

Comment: although swap memory has increased but `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` is still showing nothing. And changing the ownership for gvfs-metadata/home* doesn't has the desire effect i.e. it is not opening as desired. I am sorry I don't know much about swap memory and have to read more about it.

Comment: And desktop icons do show up but after a long time just when nautilus starts working.

Comment: After rebooting it is saying in a window that "files"  is not responding. And asking me to do a force quit.

Comment: @Delsilon `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` was only to tell me if you were using disk partition-based swap, which you weren't. Changing ownership of the two home files should allow `nautilus` to open faster. Desktop icons should appear without nautilus starting, if you've configured `Desktop Icons` as I instructed.

Comment: @Delsilon  Edit your question and show me `free -h` again, and `ls -al /home/bhavy/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/` again.

Comment: now it is showing a window asking for the force quit which is ultimately hanging my laptop.

Comment: @Delsilon Slow down. It's asking to force quit what? Is that AFTER trying to start `Files` from the Dock, or before?

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes, when I click `Files` on the dock it is asking to either wait or force quit as it is not able to open up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109029/discussion-between-delsilon-and-heynnema).

Comment: 1) No swap for sure is not a reason why nautilus would slowly start on an 8 GB RAM system 2) Note that OP indicates using 18.04, so the desktop-icons extension is not applicable there. The wrong permissions in gvfs-metadata might be the clue, though.

Comment: @vanadium Correct. Swap would not cause the Files problem, but my answer was an "all inclusive" answer :-)

Comment: I suggest to rearrange to put the (possibly, we do not know yet) main problem first, then you still can add any "all inclusive" recommendations.

Comment: @vanadium Good suggestion. I've spent hours on this, and it's still not 100% yet, but once we're finally satisfied that it's fully working, I'll do that.